Getting error "interaction_required" from azure AD
Below is my $provider object:
Using this library
$provider = new League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => $client_id,
    'clientSecret'            => $secret_value,
    'redirectUri'             => $callback_url,
    'urlAuthorize'            => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" . $tenant_id . "/oauth2/authorize",
    'urlAccessToken'          => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" . $tenant_id . "/oauth2/token",
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
]);

In my company account when I am logging in it is redirecting to below callback function and I am getting the access token under  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $accessToken; perfectly, and able to get email id and other details from this token, However when I am deploying the same code with same app configuration for my clients azure ad tenant, I am getting interaction_required error.
$e->getMessage() is printing interaction_required only, is there way we can get some more info about this error what configuration is exactly missing in my clients azure ad account? At below line I am getting error, shall I print_r($e) to get the whole message?
echo 'Authentication error: ' . $e->getMessage();

public function callback() {

    $secret_value="XXX";
    $client_id="XXX";
    $tenant_id="XXX";

    $provider = new League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
        'clientId'                => $client_id,
        'clientSecret'            => $secret_value,
        'redirectUri'             => $callback_url,
        'urlAuthorize'            => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" . $tenant_id . "/oauth2/authorize",
        'urlAccessToken'          => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" . $tenant_id . "/oauth2/token",
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    ]);

    if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
        if (!isset($_GET['state']) || $_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state']) {
            $this->logging($_GET['code'],"Invalid state parameter");
            die('Invalid state parameter');
        }

        try {
            // Exchange authorization code for access token
            $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                'code' => $_GET['code'],
            ]);

            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $accessToken;
            header('Location: https://example.com/');
            exit;
        } catch (League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
            echo 'Authentication error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    } elseif (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        die('Error: ' . $_GET['error']);
    }

}

Tried with My company account, working perfectly.
But for my client it is not working.

Ensure that the application has the necessary permissions and that consent has been granted by an administrator in your client's Azure AD tenant.

Instead of printing just the error message ($e->getMessage()), you can indeed print the entire exception (print_r($e)) to get more details about the error, which might include error codes or additional information.

Is that your client using Multi-factor Authentication?

At my own, we have enabled and we see popup of MFA(OTP then code from authenticator), however when we test it for client MFA does not comes, they are saying they have enabled MFA, however We are not sure at the moment. If they have enabled/not enabled MFA can this be a reason of token verification failure? Can there be any trusted IP issue while validating the token? Lets say when user is visiting webpage they are using there office internet, so it is trusted for there azure AD, that's why MFA popup is not coming, however when I am trying to exchange the token from my server, its failing?
